# File creation with python for users and passwords

Tags: python, file, split

I am making a user creation and login system, but when I create the user there isn't any content in the related file.

```
inp = "newuser bob password"   
if inp.startswith("newuser "):
            file = open(f".{inp.split(' ')[1] }.txt", "x")
            file.close()
            file = open(f".{inp.split(' ')[1] }.txt", "w")
            file.write(str(inp.split(' ')[2]))
```

The script runs without any problems or errors the file gets created and but it doesn't contain anything.

Comment: for me it wrote `password` into `.bob.txt` file

Comment: Did you try to *close* the file after writing to it?

Comment: A few notes. First, you don't need to open with the `x` mode as the `w` mode will create a new empty file for you anyway. Second, you should call `file.close()` at the end. Finally, you don't need to pass the `' '` to `split` in your example as it splits on whitespace by default.

Comment: Obligatory :Do not store plaintext passwords, and moreover do not try and implement authentication yourself, use an established library.

Answer (score 2):

Closing the file writes any changes. So, you should again add a close method to the end.
Code:

```py
inp = "newuser bob password"   
if inp.startswith("newuser "):
            file = open(f".{inp.split(' ')[1] }.txt", "w")
            file.write(str(inp.split(' ')[2]))
            file.close()
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to encrypt the password!